# Remove a value from a nested list not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

My college assignment so far looks like this:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
cout = [[]]*3
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        check = data[i][j]
        print(check)
        if data[i][j] % 2 == 0:
            cout[i].append(data[i][j])      

print(cout)
```

and its output was

> [[2, 4, 6, 8], [2, 4, 6, 8], [2, 4, 6, 8]]

but i want it to be

> [[2], [4, 6], [8]]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi welcome to Stackoverflow.

Change your initialization for cout to

```
cout = [[],[],[]]
```

Besides here some code how to debug your code

```
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
cout = [[],[],[]]
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        check = data[i][j]
        print("i =", i)
        print("j =",j)
        print(check)
        print(cout)
        if data[i][j] % 2 == 0:
            cout[i].append(check)      

print(cout)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to extract the even items from your 2D list. There are many ways to do this

## Using 2 `for..in` loops

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
even = []

for block in data:
    tmp = []
    for x in block:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            tmp.append(x)
    even.append(tmp)
```

## Using `lambda` functions

```
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
even = [list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, l)) for l in data]
```

## Output

```
[[2], [4, 6], [8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line `cout = [[]] * 3`. This is not creating three separate lists but 3 objects referencing to the same list. One way to fix this is to write `cout = [[], [], []]` or `cout = [[] for _ in range(3)]`.

Check the other answers for cleaner way of achieving what you are trying to achieve, though.

Comment: thank you for this info, i just learned python and pretty much innocent at this language. when i searched how to create an empty nested list, i found it to be written like this. so, giving this info really helped me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another oneliner:

```
my_lists =  [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
[l[(i+1)%2::2] for i, l in enumerate(my_lists)]
[[2], [4, 6], [8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter out uneven numbers from sublists in a list you can use nested listcomps:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

[[i for i in l if not i % 2] for l in data]
# [[2], [4, 6], [8]]
```